# Angular in Rails throws an error in production `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

When running my app in development it works fine. but when deployed, it throws this error :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

The url to the app : http://shimizu.leafycode.com/panel/signin

The js files : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/3a9e088ad3410e18030c

I followed other stack-overflow answers and fixed my app accordingly but still the problem is there! Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being minified and I can see at least one place in `app.js` where you are not using the array notation when calling `.config` and `.run`

So in your `app.js` update the line

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
```

to

```
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
    // ... Your code ...
}])
```

and the line

```
.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
```

to

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    // .. Your code ...
}])
```

Double check other places in your code that you are injecting services.

Comment: Thanks it's working... Looks like we don't have to add 'routeParams' like this.