# Error on production build but okay in development build

Tags: angularjs

I am currently taking over a project created in laravel with angular js. If I try to build it in development mode its fine. But I got error if we build the app in production.

I already tried this

[Angular in Rails throws an error in production `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779615/angular-in-rails-throws-an-error-in-production-error-injectorunpr-unknown)

and it gives me an error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.config due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NotificationConfig
```

Here is my code

```js
import {RoutesConfig} from './config/routes.config';
import {NotificationConfig} from './config/notification.config';
import {LocalstorageConfig} from './config/localstorage.config';
angular.module('app.config')
    .config(NotificationConfig)
    .config(RoutesConfig)
    .config(LocalstorageConfig)
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorsInterceptor');
    }])
```

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: NotificationConfig` well i'll state the obvious. The NotificationConfig has no provider for angular to inject with. Are you using ngAnnotate at all?

Comment: I currently don't know. How should I be able to check that?

Comment: ngAnnotate makes it easier to write angular syntax because instead of having to do:

`.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorsInterceptor');
    }])`

you can:


 `.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpErrorsInterceptor');
    })`

But if things aren't configured correctly for production (if ngAnnotate doesnt run) then the injections will break. I honestly dont know if that's your problem. Just what comes to mind first.

Comment: It is currently not used in the Project

Comment: I search for it and currently it is now deprecated.